# convert string representation of array to numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I can [convert a string representation of a list to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python) with `ast.literal_eval`. Is there an equivalent for a numpy array?

```
x = arange(4)
xs = str(x)
xs
'[0 1 2 3]'
# how do I convert xs back to an array
```

Using `ast.literal_eval(xs)` raises a `SyntaxError`. I can do the string parsing if I need to, but I thought there might be a better solution.

Comment: The numpy array doesn't provide a `repr` that can be used to reconstruct even a python list. You could doctor the string to recreate a list then create a numpy array from that e.g. `numpy.array(ast.literal_eval(', '.join(xs.split(' '))))`

Comment: Is it essential that you use `ast.literal_eval`?  If so, then the answer is *no*, you can't get a numpy array from `literal_eval`.  From the python documentation of `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`: "The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None."  If what you really want is a convenient way to convert a numpy array to a string and then back to an array, please elaborate on that in the question.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I was curious of there was an analog for `ast.literal_eval` that worked for numpy arrays, but didn't expect to use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For 1D arrays, [Numpy has a function called `fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy.fromstring), so it can be done very efficiently without extra libraries.

Briefly you can parse your string like this:

```
s = '[0 1 2 3]'
a = np.fromstring(s[1:-1], dtype=np.int, sep=' ')
print(a) # [0 1 2 3]
```

For nD arrays, one can use `.replace()` to remove the brackets and `.reshape()` to reshape to desired shape, or use Merlin's solution.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
xs = '[0 1 2 3]'

import re, ast
ls = re.sub('\s+', ',', xs)
a = np.array(ast.literal_eval(ls))
a  # -> array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: I think the other answer better answers my question as asked, yes. I cannot quite understand why you even ask this question. You had clearly answered  before I accepted an answer.

Comment: The reason is simple. The answer does not work for the code sample given!

Comment: It is a self contained example that makes quite clear how to use `np.fromstring`, a function I'd forgotten about, for the problem I was trying to solve. I also said "I can do the string parsing if I need to" in my question. So I didn't learn anything from your answer, but I learned something from the other one.

Comment: I am done here.. learning something is upvote, answering marked as correct on SO. The answer as chosen will lead ppl astray in the future.

Comment: Both answers are valid depending on the case and for future readers like me both are beneficial. +1 to both.

Comment: This solution works on 2D array encoded by str() as well, thus it really should be marked as THE answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.matrix` to convert a string to a numpy matrix. Then, use `np.asarray` to convert the matrix to a numpy array with the same shape.

```
>>> s = "[1,2]; [3,4]"
>>> a = np.asarray(np.matrix(s)) 
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

In contrast to the accepted answer, this works also for two dimensional arrays.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It solves a lot of problems altogether !

Answer (score 0):

if elements of lists are 2D float. ast.literal_eval() cannot handle a lot very complex list of list of nested list.

Therefore, it is better to parse list of list as dict and dump the string.

while loading a saved dump, ast.literal_eval() handles dict as strings in a better way. convert the string to dict and then dict to list of list

```
k = np.array([[[0.09898942, 0.22804536],[0.06109612, 0.19022354],[0.93369348, 0.53521671],[0.64630094, 0.28553219]],[[0.94503154, 0.82639528],[0.07503319, 0.80149062],[0.1234832 , 0.44657691],[0.7781163 , 0.63538195]]])

d = dict(enumerate(k.flatten(), 1))
d = str(d) ## dump as string  (pickle and other packages parse the dump as bytes)

m = ast.literal_eval(d) ### convert the dict as str to  dict

m = np.fromiter(m.values(), dtype=float) ## convert m to nparray
```