# How do you import a CSV whose elements are Numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Due to using a combination of not entirely compatible software packages, I need to be able to read a CSV file whose elements are stylized as Numpy arrays. An example of such a CSV would be the one below:

[image]

When using `genfromtxt('Input.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None,encoding=None)`, I get output of the form:

```
[['[4 3 2 1]' '[1 1 0 0]']
 ['[1 3 4 2]' '[0 1 1 0]']]
```

What I would like is to get this into the form of a three-dimensional Numpy array like below:

```
[[[4 3 2 1] [1 1 0 0]]
 [[1 3 4 2] [0 1 1 0]]]
```

Comment: What does this csv file look like in plaintext?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with numpy, but you should be able to use an answer from [convert string representation of array to numpy array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886641/convert-string-representation-of-array-to-numpy-array-in-python) and apply it to each element of the 2D array.

Comment: Try not to save arrays in that format.  Parsing it isn't fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an array from these strings dynamically (at run-time):

```
import numpy as np
import ast

# data represents the string returned by str(genfromtxt(...))
data = '[[\'[4 3 2 1]\' \'[1 1 0 0]\'] [\'[1 3 4 2]\' \'[0 1 1 0]\']]'

# remove quotes
data = data.replace('\'', '')
# insert commas
data = data.replace(' ', ', ')

# create an array 
np_data = np.array(ast.literal_eval(data))

# here's your 3D numpy array
print(np_data.shape)
print(np_data)
```

Comment: unnecessary use of exec when ast.literal_eval or json.loads would work.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm pretty sure genfromtext returns a numpy array, not a string.

Comment: @SuperStormer thanks, I've removed unnecessary use of exec()